# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'OC::OCException'

Tags: c++, iotivity

I'm running on iotivity 1.2.1 I started from simpleclient and simpleserver examples. I made two clients: The first one POST variables and the second one observe the resource (get new changes made by the first client). I wanted to run the example for, like forever. At the start the program works perfectly. The problem is after running for around one day and a half, I get this error:

```
Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'OC::OCException'
what(): Response is NULL
Aborted
```

I don't know why I get this error. Is it because I'm using an older version of IoTivity?

Comment: Look into what throws the exception and *why*.

Comment: Not trying to discourage but wondering why you are trying to get started with iotivity 1.2.1.  That version is about 2 years old and can not even be certified any longer. If you are just getting started with iotivity I would strongly recommend moving to iotivity-lite. developement on iotivity has almost stopped while developement on iotivity-lite is still very active. (not trying to be a jerk you may have very good reasons for using an old version of the software )